# Abp backend and frontend angular - Exception not wokring

Tags: c#, angular, abp

I have a abp.io backend version 7.0.0 RC and angular frontend, and my remote or backend UserFriendly exceptions are not showing in my angular application when deployed to Azure, but local they working fine.

below its how l'm showing my exceptions

```
throw new UserFriendlyException("exception message")
```

Going throught the [documents](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Exception-Handling#abpexceptionhandlingoptions) this is what i have tried and still they are not showing

```
    Configure<AbpExceptionHandlingOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SendExceptionsDetailsToClients = true;
    options.SendStackTraceToClients = false;
});
```

I have added the above to my ApplicationModule and Domain Module

Answer (score 1):

it seems the issue is not related to code it might be firewall/security policy related to the enviroment you can open developer tool on browser and check the network tab to further invistigate

Comment: You are actual right, the issue was CORS policy